# Phoenix check model (eg. user) equality

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix n00b here.

So I have a logged in current user (using [Coherence](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence), but I don't think this has impact here):

```
user = Coherence.current_user(conn)
```

And I have an object that has a relationship with a user:

```
object = Repo.get(Object, XX) |> Repo.preload(:user)
owner = object.user
```

I simply want to check that `user` is the same as `owner`.

- Writing `user == owner` is not correct because - I guess - structs are references so the two will be difference despite being the same DB object.
- Writing `user.id == owner.id` shall work but since `user` can be `nil` it will fail in that case, while the equality remains true.
- I tried `user[:id] == owner[:id]` since this doesn't fail if `user` is nil but then if it is a `user`, I get a `User does not implement the Access behaviour` error. :(
- Writing `not is_nil(user) && user.id == owner.id` works but is ugly (and thanks god `owner` is not also nillable)

I guess I'll need a helper function here, but ain't it already built-in? If so, where? In Ecto? In Coherence?

Ain't there a way to override struct equality for some specific structs?

Comment: `user == owner` should work assuming it is actually being pulled from the same table and are coming from the same module, with the caveat that the data could have changed between asking for the `user` and asking for the `owner`, so it is theoretically possible to have it be false, even if they have the same id's.

Comment: If one of the two instances has a `Repo.preload` somewhere, it fails, which is not acceptable (as those remain the same objects).

Comment: You have to remember that structs are implemented as maps. The problem with just comparing id's is that you could compare different kinds of structs and if the id's match, it will return true. I think your best option will be to create your own compare function.

Comment: So there isn't any built in function, like in `Ecto.Schema`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest: `owner = Map.get(object, :user, %{})`. You will have now 2 maps to compare.
You can then use `user[:id] == owner[:id]`

Comment: Thanks. This is not `owner` which brings me trouble but `user`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the condition in the query?

```
owner = some_struct

from(
  o in Object, 
  where: o.user_id == ^owner.id and not is_nil(o.user_id), 
  preload: [:user]
) 
|> Repo.one # !only works if db returns max one row!
|> case do
  nil ->    # no matches in db
  object -> # object.user.id == object.user_id == owner.id here
end
```

Edit: changed to hopefully something closer to what the poster wants

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. In my case, there is no `Owner` model, but two `User` preloaded entities that come from different sources and I want to check equality between the two.

Comment: Ah, so Objects can have user_id and you want to get one whose user_id is the same as owner.id?

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, comparing only the id's is probably a bad idea because it would return true even if you compare different kinds of structs. Your best bet would be to create a compare function. Something like the following will probably work for you.

```
def compare_structs(%mod{id: id}, %mod{id: id}), do: true
def compare_structs(_, _), do: false
```

This uses pattern matching to make sure that both arguments are structs, as well as coming from the same module and that they have the same `id`. Everything else passed to this function will be false.